# Triple integral clarification please

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have this question which states:

> Let $T$ be the tetrahedron bounded by the planes $x = 0, y = 0, z =0$ and $x+y+z = 2$
>
> Integrate $$J = \iiint_{T} y^2 \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
> Using the above integral, or otherwise, evaluate
> $$K = \iiint_{P}(x^2+\sin(xy^2)+ y^2) \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
>
> where $$P = \left \{(x,y,z) : 0 \leq z \leq 2 -|x| -|y|\right \}$$

My thoughts are as follows I think the first part of the question is understandable just use the limits and follow through with the solution $J = 0$ but the second part is tougher.

I'm guessing we realise (if we let) $f(x,y) = x^2y$ this is odd w.r.t. y and domain P is symmetric about y-axis. And the same for $g(x,y) = \sin(xy^2)$ which is odd w.r.t. x and P is symmetric about x-axis. We can say their integral over P is $0$

So the final solution is $$K = J = 0$$

I hope someone could either correct me and tell me how to proceed if this is wrong thank you!

Comment: $J$ can't be $0$ since you are integrating $y^2> 0$ on $T$ that has a "volume" or better lebesgue measure $>0$

Comment: Thanks @Gabrielek I'll have another go, do you have any thoughts on what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you an hint only for the triple integral $J$ and hope I will not do any stupid error.

The region you are considering is $x+y+z = 2$, $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$ and $z\ge0$.
Then you can get for example the following parameterization:
$$y\in [0,2], \quad z \in [0,2-y], \quad x \in [0,2-y-z]$$

Once you got this you can write the integral as follows:
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{2-y} \int_0^{2-y-z}y^2 \ \ dx\ dz\ dy$$

Now you just have to perform the integrations correctly and you should get $J = \frac{8}{15}$